# How to avoid edition of a denied/filtered record on Flask-Admin

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-admin

I'm filtering the records by using get_query to separate records for each user.

```
def get_query(self):
    return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.userid == current_user.id)
```

But it does not solve the problem when the user types the id of a filtered record directly in the url. How can I avoid this situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `get_one` method of your view. See the notes in the docs for [get_query](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py#L845) and [get_one](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py#L1083).

Example, assuming using SQLAlchemy:

```
def TestView(ModelView):

    def get_query(self):
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.userid == current_user.id)

    def get_count_query(self):
         self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model).filter(self.model.userid == current_user.id)

    def get_one(self, id):
        query = self.get_query()
        return query.filter(self.model.id == id).one()
```